# How can I significantly improve a query's performance without adding indices?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following pseudo-query someone wrote:

```
SELECT custId, orderId, col1, col2
FROM (SELECT c.id AS custId, o.id AS orderId,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY c.id, o.id
                        ORDER BY d.col1, d.col2) AS RANK
      FROM customers c
      INNER JOIN orders o ON c.id = o.custId
      INNER JOIN orderDetails d ON o.id = d.orderId
      WHERE d.col3 IS NULL)
WHERE RANK = 1
```

- c.id (custId) and o.id (orderId) are the only indexed fields.
- customers table has ~2 million records
- orders table has ~37 million records
- orderDetails table has ~620 million records

Unfortunately this query takes an unknown amount of time (> 2 hours) and I've been tasked with fixing this problem. So far I've come up with an alternative that runs quite a bit faster (but it's still totally unacceptabled IMHO):

```
SELECT custId, orderId, col1, col2
FROM (SELECT custId, orderId, col1, col2,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY custId, orderId
                               ORDER BY col1, col2) AS RANK
      FROM (SELECT c.id AS custId, o.id AS orderId, d.col1, d.col2, d.col3
            FROM customers c
            INNER JOIN orders o ON c.id = o.custId
            INNER JOIN orderDetails d ON o.id = d.orderId)
      WHERE col3 IS NULL
WHERE RANK = 1
```

Alas, I'm not able to add any indexes or look at the execution plans for queries based off of these tables so I'm kind of at a loss as to how I can rewrite/structure this to run significantly faster =/. Hoping one of you experts has a better idea... I'm not specifically asking because of this particular query but because we have a LOT of such queries that need to be rewritten like this and I'm trying to learn what the main problems with these are/how I can best solve them.

Comment: Without the ability to see an execution plan, it's nearly impossible to tune a statement properly.

Comment: Have a look at the execution plan(s) and try to avoid table scans.

Comment: In MS SQL I'd first grab a subset of the data from your `customers`, `orders`, and `orderDetails` tables and shove it into a table variable (an in-memory table), and then run the necessary subqueries against it rather than trying to do the same against the actual tables in the filesystem.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name You're telling me... I really wish there was something I could do about it. Unfortunately it's something my group has been forced to deal with.

Comment: Can't the DBA extract the execution plans using `dbms_xplan`?

Comment: @DarthContinent: working with temp tables in Oracle is almost always slower than working with the tables directly (if they are small enough they will be in memory anyway, if they don't fit into memory, you can't put them into a variable either).

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I'd want to try it just to use a less "busy" query to initially grab the data from the database (one without worrying about indexing and subqueries and ranks and joins) and then do those more expensive manipulations on the resulting smaller in-memory table instead of the full-sized database tables. For me with MS SQL and huge (tens of millions of rows) tables it's helped a great deal, especially in cases where the table isn't one I have the power to fix poor indexing on.

Comment: One small change that should help would be to move the "WHERE col3 IS NULL" into the innermost subquery. This will allow you to cull it down as the base table before performing any additional logic. As is you're returning all the results from that three table join before applying the Where criteria. Moving it inside should allow the query optimizer to get you a more efficient plan.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Sure they could, will they? lol...

Comment: @DarthContinent In MS SQL I'd hope you would [use a temp table rather than a table variable](http://www.sqlbadpractices.com/using-table-variable-for-large-table-vs-temporary-table/) when working with 620 million records, the optimiser will always assume that a table variable has 1 row and cannot be indexed so this would not help at all!

Comment: @GarethD: Well, in these cases I've only needed a specific subset from that huge table, like let's say a list of orders associated with a given customer which might result in a table variable of no more than a few hundred or thousand records. I'd grab those, then act upon the data in the table variable and not touch the main table any further (at least for purposes of say reporting).

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing an explain plan of the original query, I can only think about the following query for now (might need to correct the syntax but the general idea will remain the same) :-

```
with d as 
(select orderid, col1, col2
from (select orderid, col1, col2,
row_number() over (partition by orderID order by col1,col2) as RANK
from orderDetails
where col3 is null)
where RANK=1)
select c.id as custID, o.id as orderID, d.col1, d.col2
from customers c inner join orders o on c.id=o.custID
inner join d on o.id=d.orderid;
```

you might need to juggle the join order of the customers, orders and the temporary table 'd' in order to get the right combination (so that the tables with the lower number of records are joined first).

In your query, you are joining the tables and then you are fetching those records which have minimum value of col1 and col2 group per combination of c.id and o.id. Going by your query, I think it will be safe to take out partitioning by c.id since col1 and col2 are dependent on the orderID and not on customerID. So, multiple customerIDs which have same orderID will have the same value of col1 and col2.

So, the above query is first fetching the minimum value of col1 and col2 group per orderID and then joining them with the remaining tables.